# Что перенаправляет запрос с http://example.com/ на http://example.com (без слеша в конце)?

Tags: html, http

Т.е. это как бы исключение?

Ведь обычно слеш является неотъемлемой частью URL:

```
http://example.com/page
http://example.com/page/
```

это разные страницы, если я не ошибаюсь.

Спасибо.

---

PS Вопрос у меня возник в связи с указанием мультиязычных страниц для Гугла, они [рекомендуют](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=ru) указывать со слешем на конце:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

Comment: Ничего не перенаправляет. Это браузер так показывает.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Как следует указывать ссылку на главную страницу сайта? На что может повлиять отсутствие слеша? (Я добавил примечение к вопросу).

Comment: Вроде ни на что. Технически там всегда есть слеш, просто браузеры его не показывают

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я смотрел в отладчике: если набрать без слеша - никакого редиректа на главную страницу со слешем не происходит, сервер сразу возвращает код 200. Так что дело не в браузере, судя по всему. Наверно надо почитать спецификацию.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Кажется я вспомнил, в RFC 2068 вообще об этих слешах ни слова.

Comment: Я не понимаю в чём у вас проблема. Браузеру всё равно как вы набрали адрес. Корневой слеш он отправит всегда. В RFC есть 5.1 и 5.1.2

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо! Так вот и ответ:  "Обратите внимание, что абсолютный путь не может быть пустым; если оригинальный URI пуст, то он ДОЛЖЕН запрашиваться как "/" (корневой каталог сервера)". Т.е. в итоге слеш можно и не писать. Оформите как ответ, выберу решением.